# Trying to replace a symbol in a text file of 4000 lines, ends up with only 500 in Java

Tags: java

What i'm trying to do, is to replace a symbol in a file text which contains over 4000 lines but using the below code, after the program ends, it only remain 500 lines. Why is this file truncated? How to solve this?

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {    
        line = line.replace("þ", "t");
        arrayList.add(line);

        try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            for (String string : arrayList) {
                bw.write(string + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {System.err.println(e);}
    }
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you writing lines to the new file in the same loop that reads the lines?

Comment: Yes looks like every time you read a line from the input, you then re-write all previous lines again to the new file.  So read line 1, write line 1.  Read line 2, write line 1 + line 2.  Read line 3, write line 1 + line 2 + line 3 .....

Comment: @NicholasSmith I understand. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: **AND** you are writing to the file while you are reading it - definitely not a good plan. You'd be better off writing to a new file and then renaming the old one to `.old` and renaming the new one to the correct name at the end of your pass.

Comment: Just move the writing part out of the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to the same file while you are reading it. This won't work. Once you start writing, the file becomes empty (plus whatever you've written), so subsequent reads will report end-of-file. Your ~500 lines will be buffered input from the first read.

One solution is to do all the reading first, before opening the file again for writing:

```
Array<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {

    while ((String line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {    
        line = line.replace("þ", "t");
        arrayList.add(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
   for (String string : arrayList) {
      bw.write(string + "\n");
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.err.println(e);
}
```

Here, *first* the program slurps the file into a `List<String>`, fixing the lines as it goes. *Then* it writes all the lines back out to the file.

There are circumstances in which this model is appropriate. For example, you might be building a non-linear data structure from the file content. Or you might need to see the last line before you can modify earlier lines (and be unable to re-open the data source from the start).

**However** I'd suggest a method that's more thrifty with memory. You don't need to keep all those lines in memory. You can read one line, fix it up, then forget about it. But to do this, you'll need to write to a second file.

```
String filein = "inputfile";
String fileout = filein + ".tmp";

try(
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filein));
   Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(FileWriter(fileout))
) {
      while ((String line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {    
          writer.write(line.replace("þ", "t");
      }
}

Files.move(Paths.get(fileout)), 
           Paths.get(filein), 
           CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

I have left out the necessary exception catching -- add back in as required.

Comment: Completely understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))` clear file.

You should open it only once. Also you reading and writing to the same file. You should use different files.

Like this

```
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.replace("þ", "t");

            bw.write(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @kh.Taheri you don't need to close while using try-with-resource

Comment: @Kh.Taheri Try-with-resource do it for you.

Comment: The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. So Talex's code is ok